# Text in p tag is not breaking to new lines

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at the following image:

[image]

And here is the code with the problem:

```
<div class="excerpt">
 <p>Manual para la descarga e instalación de los contenidos digitales del Proyecto Canaima&nbsp;Educativo,&nbsp;conformado&nbsp;por&nbsp;recursos&nbsp;de&nbsp;aprendizaje&nbsp;que&nbsp;buscan&nbsp;impulsar&nbsp;la&nbsp;interacción&nbsp;entre&nbsp;el[...]</p>
</div>
```

For some bizarre reason the text is getting on top of the columns to the right. I tried changing the height of all of the elements taking part to 1000px, and they are STILL overlapping!

EDIT: Question had a link originally so now that it was succesfully answered I changed it with an image per @Roddy of the Frozen Peas suggested.

As some people suggested, if you remove the & nbsp; the problem goes away. But that was not the case as it looks like the admin was inserting those & nbsp; and I have no saying in changing the admin. So the accepted answer finally solved it.

Comment: Don't use `&nbsp;`

Comment: It's because you are using `&nbsp;` spaces rather than normal space characters. The browser doesn't know where to wrap the text so leaves it on one line.

Comment: Please copy-paste the relevant code into your question, so that in the future when your link is no longer showing the problem this question is still useful to visitors.

Comment: To the people telling me to not use &nbsp; the code is being generated by the Wordpress Admin System, so I don't know if there is much I can do about that

Comment: @JoshC perhaps... but that is not my decision to make :( it was the client's choice

Comment: @AlexanderScholz I don't think he is inserting `&nbsp`. It is probably a CSM that is doing it. I have known in the past for some users to have issues with drupal doing this and engineers never managing to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I just did. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I also uploaded an image now to better visualize the problem. Do you have a suggestion for the title? As I know that is very generic as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoshC He's done a good job of making it non-Spanish.. ! :) Deserves an upvote

Comment: Thanks @MackieeE ! I actually just removed the link as it no longer portrayed the problem. Just left the image

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use: `word-wrap: break-word;` on your paragraph elements. That'll then start forcing them to start a new line.

```
.entry-footer .excerpt p {
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

See [firefox word-wrap documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).

Comment: This fixed it. I can't accept it for another 7 minutes though!

Comment: It may of fixed it but the root of the actual problem was as @AlexanderScholz stated, the *&nbsp;* treated the paragraph as one whole entire string and thus overflowed, remove them - and it's back to normal. Oh and, gracias! :)

Comment: @MackieeE The problem still resides but a solution has been provided to stop the problem from being a problem. I would assume the `$nbsp` are from a cms entry system that needs tweaking.

Comment: Yeah, someone else pointed that out as well, but like I said to him, that is being generated by the admin of the site (Wordpress) and I have no access to that. Thanks again! :D

Comment: @Vector you are assuming correctly :D That is why I chose this answer

Comment: try: ``white-space: normal;``

Answer (score 6):

There is a lot of white space being generated withing your `html`. add this to your CSS

```
div.excerpt p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: this fixes it, but @MackieeE answered first... thanks anyway!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed :)